# FQL multiquery vs. subquery

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to query mutual likes between two users. The multiquery version works as expected, but if I insert the first query as subquery in the second one I get an empty array as result. They actually doing exact the same thing. Why?

Working:

```
"like_ids" : "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=5678", 
"mutual_like_ids" : "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=1234 AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #like_ids)"
```

Not working:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=1234 AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=5678)
```

Comment: Have you tried running your subquery separate from the whole thing? My first suspicion would be that it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Of course this query doesn't return anything, because the uids are fake. But otherwise it runs fine. And the two queries are EXACTLY the same.

Comment: Then try with real uids. I can see that queries are the same, this is why i'm offering you to run it step by step

Comment: The uids are really not the problem. I tried with real ones.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with this then: 
"but the subqueries cannot reference variables in the outer query's  scope"

Taken from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#query